# UserMap, getting NAME for User, not ID, in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

UPDATED 1pm EST:

I am working with THIS line of code, where LEFT of the equals sign is NOT the issue, ONLY the usermap reference.  I am trying to replace the OwnerID with the actual NAME from the User database.

```
accObj.put('pb_Close_Owner_' + tempFieldName + '__c',  userMap.get(tmpClosedWonOwner).name );
```

.
.

ORIGINAL POST:

What if you are trying to populate the Owner Name from a VARIABLE that contains the ID of the user? How would this one line change?

```
c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId).name;
```

(ABOVE THIS IS NOT THE CODE I'M WORRIED ABOUT, SEE BELOW)

I tried some variations but can't get it to work. I ENVISION it being something similar to:

```
accObj.put('xx',  userMap.tmpClosedWonOwner.name );
```

Thanks. *(this is a cut down version of the code I'm using, hence the diff on the left - I am using a reference to a previous Answer on the first codeset)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely either accountMap or userMap are returning null and then throwing an error when you try to reference the null value or have not been initialized themselves. Try the folllowing:

```
system.debug('accountMap: '+ accountMap);
system.debug('userMap: 'userMap)

Account acc = accountMap.get(c.AccountId);
system.debug('account: '+acc);

User u = userMap.get(acc.OwnerID);
system.debug('user: '+u);

c.MerchantOwner__c = u.name;
```

Comment: I never should have posted the FIRST code sample.  It's not representative of what I am doing - it's from another Answer here on SE.  The SECOND one is my example, and it is *never* null in my particular circumstance.   :-/

Comment: Latest code attempt (with fix for GET) below:

Comment: accObj.put('pb_Close_Owner_' + tempFieldName + '__c',  userMap.get(tmpClosedWonOwner).name );

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: userMap.get(String) at line 434 column 80

Comment: Can you clean up your question a bit? Just put the line that you are having issues with, the exact error you get, and the definitions of accObj, tempFieldName, userMap, tmpClosedWonOwner, etc.

Comment: I have added a disclaimer to the original posting, thanks.   Next msg = def'ns....

Comment: accObj references our Account object for writing purposes, tempFieldName is a simple string, the RIGHT of the equal sign is the issue.  This code works FINE if you replace the right of the equals sign with JUST the tmpClosedWonOwnwer variable.  I'm trying to replace the User ID with the User Name to write to this String variable on the Account.   :-/

Comment: is userMap a map<ID,User> or map<string,User>?

Comment: Let's discuss this in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6134/room-for-grigriforce-and-amm

Comment: Wow.   As I was thinking about this, I am realizing the code I ripped off is the issue.  usermap is not a canned item, is it.   :-(    I want to hang my head in shame now.  Let's see if I can figure out the right syntax now.......  (feel FREE to post it so I don't have to ask in 5 minutes)    :-/   THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: glad to help. I'll be in the chatroom I created above for a while if you want to discuss this. Also, you should go back and make sure to upvote/accept the answers to your previous questions if they helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId
```

This above code has error .Since the output from the map accountMap.get(c.AccountId) i assume its a record and say record is type account named 'NewAccount' and now you cannot refer as a field as NewAccount.ownerId.

The second one is dynamic dml where you input both field token and value and hence its valid.

Comment: The second one does not work.

Comment: Variable does not exist: userMap.tmpClosedWonOwner.name  ... apparently I need to reference the "tmp" var differently here.

Comment: Tried:                                   accObj.put('pb_Close_Owner_' + tempFieldName + '__c',  userMap.(tmpClosedWonOwner).name );
           but error was:       Method does not exist or incorrect signature: userMap.(String)

Comment: accObj.put('pb_Close_Owner_' + tempFieldName + '__c',  userMap.get(tmpClosedWonOwner).name );

Comment: Sorry, I realized what you were implying, and I also realized my bad syntax to begin with.  The above is NOW what I'm using, but still getting the last error I posted:   - - - -   Method does not exist or incorrect signature: userMap.get(String)